# AngularJS model object value can't change using dynamic key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', function ($scope, $location, authService) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.$onInit = function () {
        vm.active = {
            "home": true,
            "welcome": false,
            "user": false,
            "logout": false,
            "login": false,
            "signup":false
        };
    };

    $scope.$watch('vm.active', function (newObj, oldObj) {
        Object.keys(newObj).filter(function (key) {
            vm.active[key] = newObj[key] !== oldObj[key];
            return vm.active[key];
        });
    }, true);

}]);
```

Here i try to change `vm.active` object property but it shows below error :

> angular.js:14642 Error:
>   [$rootScope:infdig]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$rootScope/..
>       at angular.js:88
>       at m.$digest (angular.js:18248)
>       at b.$apply (angular.js:18480)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (angular.js:27290)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)

Comment: have you considered using a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the error because your code is causing an infinite $digest loop because you are trying to change the model during the digest loop.

To solve the problem avoid changing the model using $watch.